# Need of separate security plugins for both root and subfolder sites Wordpress?

Tags: database

In Wordpress,

I have my main site at **www.MySite.com**
Planning to start a forum at **www.MySite.com/Forum (Subfolder)**

Do I need to have separate security plugins, for e.g. Wordfence at root & subfolder, both?

If yes, does this have any complications, I DON't want to use and get into complexities of WP Multi Site.

Thanks in advance.
Sahil

Comment: So your main site is WordPress and you want to install another WordPress site to power your forum in a sub-directory? I don't see why you would need a separate installation as most of the forum plugins are likely configurable to run from a custom URL like `/forum`. Please add a little more detail to your question else it may end up closed.

Comment: I did some research and decided to do a subfolder installation as none of the forum plugins would include all the features we wanted (standalone) so we decided to do a separate theme (Discy forum ThemeForest). This is why we are going for www.mysite/com/forum (new WP, new Theme, to complement the main root site) Feel free to suggest a better approach, if available, please.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the plugin. Some security plugins have settings that will check folders outside of the current WP install. Others don't. Some plugins may have complications if they are installed both places. Others won't.

With Wordfence specifically, both sites would need the plugin installed, and there are not issues with running the plugin in two "nested" sites. You'll just want to double-check that it's not set to scan folders outside of WP.

Comment: Also it depends on how they implementing the forum. if they use two different wp installations, then I think it's better to have two installations. if the forum is not wp, then wp security plugins wont monitor that area AFAIK

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help.

**Quick Question** - is subfolder approach viable & good for a forum in case if the publisher discovers that none of the WP plugins out there gives him all the rich features he wants, therefore, he needs a forum-dedicated-theme installed at the subfolder instead of a plugin-driven-forum at the root? my approach is long-term.

Comment: Setup - whether you want to have a single site or two separate sites - comes down more to permissions. i.e. does the publisher want to maintain two separate WP logins, so when they change their password on one site they have to remember to also change it on the other site? Do they want to have to manage static content (main site) separately from moderating forum comments (forum site)? Do they want to have to update WP Core, plugins, and themes in two separate places? If you're going the custom development route seems like a single site might simplify matters for all involved.